# How to open Firefox on a remote machine but get the display on the local machine using SSH?

Tags: firefox, ssh

I've logged into the remote machine via ssh and used the command

`firefox --display:192.168.1.2:0`

Where `192.168.1.2` is the IP address of the local machine.

But it says "`Error: cannot open display: 192.168.1.2:0`"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** on the remote machine. It should contain this:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Restart sshd.

Login to remote via ssh as usual but don't forget to use **-X** option (enable X11 forwarding). Using **-C** (compression) is also recommended because X through ssh will be `much slower` than through telnet anyway.
Once you logged in, without setting **DISPLAY** yourself, type

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
```

it should show this strange value:

```
localhost:10.0
```

It's strange but perfect. Now you can just type

```
firefox
```

and wait for its window to open. Wait really means *wait* because unless the remote machine is very close to you, it will take a while. Be patient.

Comment: for me only Editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config  with "X11UseLocalhost no" worked.

Comment: I'm ssh'd into an Ubuntu machine from my Mac, with XQuartz running locally. `xeyes` and `xclock` work fine, but `firefox` just echoes `Terminated`. Any idea?

Comment: @RoyTinker - I've been trying to figure this out for a bit this morning.  Even if I open up a remote xterm, running Firefox (and Chromium) from inside that xterm says "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication."  Which is ridiculous.  As it turns out, the problem is Firefox (and Chromium) are snaps and Snap breaks paths for apps.  The fix is `export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority` first and then magically firefox & chromium and most other X11-based snaps work.

Answer (score 1):

if running from an unix like host (ubuntu for instance), try

```
ssh -X
```

according to ssh man page

```
 -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-
         host basis in a configuration file.

         X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
         ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
         user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 dis-
         play through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be
         able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.

         For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY
         extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y
         option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for
         more information.
```

if running from windows, be sure to have a X session tools like Xming.

for Xming, set display number in Xming (e.g. 1234) allow all host, instruct putty to use display number 1234, and check "forward X11 connection".